# Update Expresso Store SKU

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible to update the SKU for products in Expresso Store? Is there something I am missing? Inputting a new value and hitting submit on an entry isn’t saving the new value… HALP!

Comment: Which version of Store and EE are you running? Are the SKU's in relation to product modifiers or a regular product?

Comment: We are having the same issue. Once a SKU has been entered we are unable to modify the sku after the fact. Please fix this ASAP, affecting clients production. Gracious! EE v2.7.2 - Build Date: 20131008 Expresso 2.0.3

Comment: Are you definitely running v2.0.3? There was a known issue in v2.0.2 which was fixed which sounds very similar to this.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this is fixed by updating to Expresso Store version 2.0.3